# Reset a form but not the hidden elements

Tags: javascript, forms

After and ajax submit I want to clear the elements of a form excepting the hidden elements:

```
 function resetForm(form) {

    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        // ! do not clean hidden
        if (form.elements[i].type !== 'submit' || ...hidden...?  ) {
            form.elements[i].value = '';
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to get hidden, and a second issue, in Firefox after submit, if a I reset `form.elements[i].value = ''`, trigger the html5 invalidate(like maxlength).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `AND` operator because you should not reset `submit` and `hidden` input.
See this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
    // ! do not clean hidden
    if (form.elements[i].type !== 'submit' && form.elements[i].type !== 'hidden'  ) {
        form.elements[i].value = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use the built-in method [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) for that purpose.

The advantage is that it allows you to reset not only text fields, but uncheck the boxes that weren't checked by default, check the ones that were checked by default, reset the dropdown, that can't be done using `form.elements[i].value = '';`

In example :

```
form.reset();
```

```js
function resetForm()
{
  let form = document.getElementById("MyForm");
  let hidden = document.getElementById("MyHidden");
  console.log("hidden value BEFORE reset : " + hidden.value);
  form.reset();
  console.log("hidden value AFTER reset : " + hidden.value);
}
```

```html
<form id="MyForm">
  text 1
  <input type="text"><br />
  text 2
  <input type="text"><br />
  un-ticked checkbox
  <input type="checkbox"><br />
  ticked checkbox
  <input type="checkbox" checked><br />
  <select>
      <option>Value 1</option>
      <option>Value 2</option>
      <option>Value 3</option>
      <option>Value 4</option>
  </select><br />
  <input type="radio" id="val1" name="radio" value="1" checked>
  <label for="val1">Value 1</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="val2" name="radio" value="2">
  <label for="val2">Value 2</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="val3" name="radio" value="3">
  <label for="val3">Value 3</label><br />


  <input type="hidden" id="MyHidden" value="42">
  <button type="button" onclick="resetForm()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your hidden element is set to a value via
`<input type='hidden' value='afasd'>` 
you can use 
`document.getElementById("myForm").reset();`.

This will reset the form do the default values.

Edit 1:

It even work if you change the hidden field via js to another value. It won't be resetted.

Comment: Same idea as Cid's answer.